# Delete old partitions mysql

Tags: mysql

In my mysql database I have a table in which I have to store data for 3 months. The data gets populated in this table continuously through a kafka stream. Because this table has a lot of data I am considering partitioning it based on date of data so that each record gets added to the partition of that specific date. I am wondering how do I setup a spring boot task or a task inside db so that all partitions older than 3 months get truncated/dropped on a regular interval? What would that query look like?

Comment: [PARTITION Maintenance in MySQL - by Rick James](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint) (there undoubtly exists a existing answer). Which MySQL version are you using, there may be simplifications?

Comment: Using 8 and above

Comment: And I would recommend either weekly or daily partitions.  There is no need, nor any benefit, to specify which partition for the inserts to go into.  The link above was written long before MySQL 8.9, but nothing substantive has changed.